# doctor appointment database design

Tags: database-design

I have an application for doctors . pateints should can set appoint time .
I designed this :

[image]

an example :

```
date : 2016/22/8 has some times like : 09:00 , 09:45 , 14:30 users can selec on of them
```

is this design good ?

Comment: Maybe you can merge timeofdays and days making a table just with datetimes.

Comment: @vercelli I seperated that to avoid repeat date for each time , If i have 10 times in a day I should repeat 10 times that data .

Comment: Yes, but in that case you are storing dayid anyway

Answer (score 2):

You need to consider one more parameter, if you are doing it for multispeciality hospital, you should add a

Doctor table,

Department table, also

Doctor schedule (ex: Mon-Wed 10 am to 2pm, Thus-Sat 12 pm to 4pm )

Comment: thanks  , but my system just has one doctor always . in this way doctor doesn't can set this time in schedule : `Mon 10:30 am to 11.30px and this day again Mon 14:00pm to 15:00 pm `

Comment: With your above mentioned Scenario, I guess you have enough table if you already have `patient` table